# How do I color add a css style to an element inside another element

Tags: html, css

I have a  thing that is set up as

```css
#messages li { 
    padding: 5px 10px; 
    background: pink; 
    color:red;
}
/*
What I tried but didn't work:
#messages li #deleteButton { 
    background: pink; 
    color:lightblue;
}
*/
#messages li:nth-child(odd) {
    background: lightblue; 
    color:blue;
}
.deleteButton {
    border:0;
    padding:5px;
    border-radius:25px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="messages">
    <li id="72828282">User:Message<button class="deleteButton">Delete</button></li>
    <li id="65885852">User:Message<button class="deleteButton">Delete</button></li>
    <li id="32235282">User:Message<button class="deleteButton">Delete</button></li>
    <li id="99609282">User:Message<button class="deleteButton">Delete</button></li>
    <li id="28287282">User:Message<button class="deleteButton">Delete</button></li>
    <li id="52828282">User:Message<button class="deleteButton">Delete</button></li>
</ul>
```

What I want is that the button in even messages to have the color scheme of  the odd messages and vise versa. I would like to achieve this without using two separate classes because the messages are caught and added to the list via JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understood correctly.

Like this?

ps: Also in your comment you are targeting an id `#deleteButton` but it is set as class.

```css
#messages li { 
    padding: 5px 10px; 
    background: pink; 
    color:red;
}

#messages li button {
    background-color: lightBlue;
    color: blue;
}

#messages li:nth-child(odd) {
    background: lightblue; 
    color:blue;
}

#messages li:nth-child(odd) button {
    background-color: pink;
    color: red;
}

.deleteButton {
    border:0;
    padding:5px;
    border-radius:25px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="messages">
    <li id="72828282">User:Message<button class="deleteButton">Delete</button></li>
    <li id="65885852">User:Message<button class="deleteButton">Delete</button></li>
    <li id="32235282">User:Message<button class="deleteButton">Delete</button></li>
    <li id="99609282">User:Message<button class="deleteButton">Delete</button></li>
    <li id="28287282">User:Message<button class="deleteButton">Delete</button></li>
    <li id="52828282">User:Message<button class="deleteButton">Delete</button></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize I was targeting an id instead of the class.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this:

```css
#messages li { 
    padding: 5px 10px; 
    background: pink; 
    color:red;
}

#messages li:nth-child(odd) .deleteButton { 
    background: pink; 
    color:red;
}
#messages li:nth-child(even) .deleteButton { 
    background: lightblue; 
    color:blue;
}

#messages li:nth-child(odd) {
    background: lightblue; 
    color:blue;
}
.deleteButton {
    border:0;
    padding:5px;
    border-radius:25px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="messages">
    <li id="72828282">User:Message<button class="deleteButton">Delete</button></li>
    <li id="65885852">User:Message<button class="deleteButton">Delete</button></li>
    <li id="32235282">User:Message<button class="deleteButton">Delete</button></li>
    <li id="99609282">User:Message<button class="deleteButton">Delete</button></li>
    <li id="28287282">User:Message<button class="deleteButton">Delete</button></li>
    <li id="52828282">User:Message<button class="deleteButton">Delete</button></li>
</ul>
```